# Attribute class "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\repositoryClass" vich/uploader-bundle

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

i get this error when try install

```
composer require vich/uploader-bundle
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update vich/uploader-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                      Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "6.2.*"
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking vich/uploader-bundle (2.1.1)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading vich/uploader-bundle (2.1.1)
  - Installing vich/uploader-bundle (2.1.1): Extracting archive
Package sensio/framework-extra-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use Symfony instead.
Package sonata-project/cache is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
135 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Symfony operations: 1 recipe (e171e2df28a470782f12a212ba4300e6)
  -  WARNING  vich/uploader-bundle (>=1.13): From github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib:main
    The recipe for this package comes from the "contrib" repository, which is open to community contributions.
    Review the recipe at https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/main/vich/uploader-bundle/1.13

    Do you want to execute this recipe?
    [y] Yes
    [n] No
    [a] Yes for all packages, only for the current installation session
    [p] Yes permanently, never ask again for this project
    (defaults to n): y
  - Configuring vich/uploader-bundle (>=1.13): From github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib:main
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  
!!   // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true                  
!!  
!!  13:00:02 CRITICAL  [php] Uncaught Error: Attribute class "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\repositoryClass" not found ["exception" => Error { …}]
!!  
!!  In AttributeReader.php line 60:
!!                                                                      
!!    Attribute class "Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\repositoryClass" not found  
!!                                                                      
!!  
!!  cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers]
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

here is my composer

```
  "require": {
        "php": ">=8.2.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.3",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.14",
        "friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle": "^2.4",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^3.2",
        "gnikyt/basic-shopify-api": "^11.0",
        "itbcode/itbcodepack": "dev-master",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "*",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^6.2",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "^5.0",
        "martin-georgiev/postgresql-for-doctrine": "^2.1",
        "moneyphp/money": "^3.3",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.66",
        "openai-php/client": "^0.6.1",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.16",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.2",
        "shopify/shopify-api": "^4.2",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^4.22",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^4.10",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^5.6",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/asset": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/intl": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/mercure-bundle": "^0.3.6",
        "symfony/mime": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/process": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/rate-limiter": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/string": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/translation": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "6.2.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.16",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.2.*",
        "symfonycasts/verify-email-bundle": "^1.13",
        "tbbc/money-bundle": "^5.0",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "2.1.1"
    },
```

Comment: I would do a CASE-SENSITIVE search in your entire repo for `repositoryClass` and I'm sure you will find the problem.